# SharePoint 2010: Copy documents between lists

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

What is the best way to copy all documents from one sharepoint document list to another programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? If not, this belongs on Superuser (I think).

Comment: @C.Ross, thanks for the comment, yes I meant programmatically, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
            SPDocumentLibrary fromList = (SPDocumentLibrary)SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList(ListNames.DocmentListName);

            SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPDocumentLibrary toList = (SPDocumentLibrary)currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList(ListNames.DocmentListName);

            SPFileCollection collection = fromList.RootFolder.Files;

            foreach (SPFile item in collection)
            {
                toList.RootFolder.Files.Add(item.Url, item.OpenBinary());
            }
```